# Remove Qty Box from mini cart and the page of checkout page

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, overriding

[image]I have a site to buy a unique product (qty =1) so i need to eliminate Qty from mini cart, i just overrided /web/template/minicart/item/default.html : i removed div Qty but she still there any idea how to override and what to override exactly thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to remove the qty box. Right?

Comment: yes the label and the box of qty

Comment: Check my answer. You need to run the static-content deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the following file:

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

to your theme:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html

And remove the qty code like below:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Now run static-content deploy and check.

**For Checkout Cart Page:**

Copy the file

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml

to your theme:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

and remove the Qty from table head.

Now copy the file

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

to your theme:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

And remove the Qty block.

Refresh the cache and check.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i will check this code immediatly

Comment: still there !!!!

Comment: i think that  there is another template that we need to override do you have any idea and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you goto pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html and delete that file and run static content deploy again. It should work.

Comment: Do you mean pub/static/frontend/magento/luma /en_US/Magento_checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html

Comment: My theme extand from blank

Comment: Do one thing delete the whole folder pu/static/frontend and then run static content deploy.

Comment: it works very well  for me thank you very much brother!!! one more question how to remove it from the chekout page in the screenshot

Comment: You mean from cart page?

Comment: Yes the cart page

Comment: Check my updated answer.