# Remove Qty Box from minicart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I overrided the default.phtml under `module -checkout` and eliminated the qty box and i did flush cache and deleted folder under static except`.htaccess`

But still having the qty box after refreshing the page. so can anyone please help me figure out the error and thanks in advance

Comment: did you deploy the static-content and also which deploy:mode are you working on ?

Comment: i am workin on developper mode

Comment: ok i forget to run this command now it works fine thank you very much

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sharing any code so i share you link about how to Remove Qty Box from minicart? kindly check & compare your code with given below link it will be be helpful to you.

[magento.stackexchange.com/238709](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238703/remove-qty-box-from-mini-cart-and-the-page-of-checkout-page/238709)

[magento.stackexchange.com/208031](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208031/magento-2-minicart-disable-quanity-box?rq=1)